# Como resolver o problema método não aceitar tipos de outras classes?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Na classe de `TesteRestaurante`, eu tento passar o `almoco` como o objeto do método `cadastrarCardapio`, mas não funciona porque o objeto deve ser um `Almoco`, mas gostaria de manter a abstração da classe abstrata com os objetos `Janta`, `Almoco` e `CafeDaManha`.

Classe abstrata Cardapio

```
    public abstract class Cardapio {

    CafeDaManha cafeDaManha;
    Almoco almoco;
    Janta janta; 

    
}
```

Classe CafeDaManha

```
    public class CafeDaManha {
    
}
```

Classe Almoco

```
public class Almoco {
    
}
```

Classe Janta

```
    public class Janta {

}
```

Classe SistemaRestaurante

```
    import java.util.List;

public class SistemaRestaurante {
    
    private List<Cardapio> cardapios;

    public void cadastrarCardapio (Cardapio cardapio){
        if(cardapio != null && !this.cardapios.contains(cardapio))
        cardapios.add(cardapio);
    }


}
```

Classe TesteRestaurante

```
    public class TesteRestaurante {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        CafeDaManha cafeDaManha = new CafeDaManha();
        Almoco almoco = new Almoco();
        Janta janta = new Janta();

        SistemaRestaurante sistemaRestaurante = new SistemaRestaurante();
        sistemaRestaurante.cadastrarCardapio(almoco);


    }

}
```

Comment: Tome cuidado com a modelagem. Um restaurante possui um cardápio de descrições de pratos, pratos estes que são servidos durante refeições em horários específicos. Uma refeição não é o prato, a refeição é um período no qual o prato é feito e servido. Conceitualmente falando, não faz sentido uma refeição ou prato estender um cardápio. Cada substantivo ou expressão substantiva nesta descrição de requisitos é candidata a uma classe ou atributo de classe do sistema, podendo eventualmente ser descartada da lista de candidatos mediante critérios. Sugiro estudar Análise e Projeto Orientados a Objetos.

Comment: Isto se quiser mesmo ir pelo caminho de orientação a objetos, o que não é uma obrigatoriedade (a não ser que se trate de trabalho de curso). É importante preocupar-se em dar nomes certos às coisas, por exemplo em `cadastrarCardapio()` creio que o que você queria fazer era `cadastrarItemDeCardapio()` ou `cadastrarPrato()`, ou talvez melhor ainda, `cardapioDoCafe.adicionar(PratoDoCafe prato)...` caso tenha pensado em cardápios distintos para cada refeição.

Comment: @Piovezan Obrigado pela resposta. Devo usar o diagrama UML antes de modelar as classes do sistema de restaurante? Pois será apenas um Crud usando heranças

Comment: UML é apenas uma notação. É interessante conhecer pois normalmente está associada a APOO, e é interessante conhecer ao menos um método de APOO se pretende aprender a usar OO. Mas pode modelar como quiser, minhas sugestões foram apenas no sentido de evitar erros muito óbvios ao modelar as classes do sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários problemas conceituais nesse código, mas não vou entrar aqui porque não é o foco. Vou apenas corrigir o que precisa para compilar, mas cuidado para não treinar o erro, você se acostuma com ele e fará sempre assim.

O grande problema é que não está fazendo herança, e por isso não pode fazer polimorfismo. Então o método que aceita um tipo que não tem hierarquia não pode receber um objeto de outro tipo. Ele só poderá receber outro tipo da mesma hierarquia, que só acontecerá com a herança. Veja:

```
import java.util.*;
    
abstract class Cardapio {
    CafeDaManha cafeDaManha;
    Almoco almoco;
    Janta janta; 
}

class CafeDaManha extends Cardapio {}

class Almoco extends Cardapio {}

class Janta extends Cardapio {}

class SistemaRestaurante {
    private List<Cardapio> cardapios = new ArrayList<Cardapio>();
    public void cadastrarCardapio (Cardapio cardapio) {
        if(cardapio != null && !this.cardapios.contains(cardapio))
        cardapios.add(cardapio);
    }
}

class TesteRestaurante {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CafeDaManha cafeDaManha = new CafeDaManha();
        Almoco almoco = new Almoco();
        Janta janta = new Janta();
        SistemaRestaurante sistemaRestaurante = new SistemaRestaurante();
        sistemaRestaurante.cadastrarCardapio(almoco);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fz6OJq). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/bgvlqdbriz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Inheritance.java).

Tem material aqui no site para aprender muitos dos conceitos de forma correta. Inclusive sobre os termos e conceitos que eu usei aqui na resposta.